# ajax wont change the specified value onSucess call

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify

this project is is hosted on shopify but i will explain what everything does so you dont need to know how shopify works.

here is the site i'll be referring to. ( http://www.republicway.myshopify.com/collections/united-states ) regarding the stars you see and their readonly on this page.

i'm using a star rating system called ([JRating](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jRating/demo))

here is the section i'm having a problem with.
as you can see in the code im trying to set data equal a value received from my localhost
the value does come through i have tried with alert. but it wont set the numeric value in data.
what basically is happen is the  gets rendered through the jrating library found on the bottom of the page that i provided then using ajax i set the data value based on the id sent over. the id does coem back with a value via json but it wont work for some reason. i have also tried regular html to see if the rating works and it did.

```
<div id="spinner" style='display:none;'> <img src="{{ 'spinner.gif' | asset_url  }}"> </div>

    <div class="rating" ></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://69.231.223.112:8888/shopify/shopifyajax.php?jsoncallback=?',
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'page=collection&id={{ product.id }}', //shopify command displays a number like 11202
            dataType: "json",


            beforeSend: function() 
            {
                $("#spinner").show();
                $(".rating").attr("data", '0');

            },
            complete: function() 
            {
                $("#spinner").hide();
            },
            success: function(result) 
            {
                    var value = parseInt(result.rvalue);
                    $(".rating").attr("data", value);

            },

        });

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: can you console.log   var value = parseInt(result.rvalue); value in firebug and see the output

Comment: i get 10 and 0. 10 for the first product and 0 for the second. this does work i have tested with alert already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this site (from what you want get JSON) on your host? As I know - cross-domain requests are forbidden.. You can use something like proxy for your request - get page from PHP (file_get_contents or other function) and do your request to this file (proxy.php or other) where this content is stored.

Comment: i can do cross domain request using jsonrequest? that is why its there. the site is stored on shopify.com and i cannot use php in it. its one of those sites where you can only use their templating systems and pull and send data via ajax. the place its retrieving from is my localhost.

Comment: ps: i am receiving the value that i requested. i am able to type alert(value) and i see the value of 5. but it is not being set in place. there has to be some conflict between my ajax and the plugin.

Comment: @sarmen you are right , your ajax call is successful , can you set that value to some dom html element and check if operations are working fine.

Comment: i moved it to local its having the same problem. i set it alone so i can see what is wrong here is the link http://69.231.223.112:8888/shopify/test.php

Comment: i also set it in a dom element and the value shows up. im pretty sure now there is conflict with the plugin. i just dont know where

Comment: i figured it out thanks all. i called the jRating rendering in the success function and it worked. thanks for everything